# Is there a word "Pisser" in English gambling?

Tags: american-english, terminology, slang, colloquial-language, neologisms

[I have happened to see a Japanese anime, which is about a natural born gambler,](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FmSTNfPVfBM) (with English subtitles)

And they (The honcho group and other "workers") are gambling dices.

From 22:51 ～　The honcho explains the general rule of the dice throwing gambling.

From 24:27　～　The honcho explains about the "pisser" which is if the thrower's dices are pushed out of the cup, it is called "pisser".

Although there are several references to "bust" used here and there (in the English subtitles) "pisser" is categorized as something special.

My first question is,

1. Is there any "pisser" related word associated with gambling in English? (As far as my research led me, I have not been able to find a one that directly connects with gambling.)

And the second question is,

2. Is there anything in the English gambling world that resembles like that in the movie?

Comment: Are you saying they translated pisser from Japanese?

Comment: I am not saying, but the English subtitle would've been attached for probably broadcasting this anime in the U.S,

Comment: The word is in the sub-titles?

Comment: @Lambie Yes, from 24:19～ The honcho explains what the "pisser" is. But I think You native speakers would have more understanding about this game should you listen to the "general rule" the Honcho is explaining from 22:51～ Thank you.

Comment: Like Jamie says at her/his answer, it is quite rare here too to hear the word....

Comment: One die, three dice. The word "die" has an irregular plural. From what I saw, the subtitles are done  quite well (I only watched four minutes though).

Comment: @Mari-Lou A It's O.K, though Kaiji ( this movie ) is very famous for women too in my country. Again thanks kindest and warmest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pisser is not a normal English gambling term. It sounds like they made up the term specifically for that game.

Answer (score 2):

I think in this anime, pisser, which is in quotation marks, might be a macho-related remark in Japanese, related to a man pissing outside the toilet bowl.

However, that is a guess. As far as I know, pisser is not a gambling term.

That said, it does work in the anime.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, Lambie's intuition is correct. If we look at the dialogue, which is translated into good English, we hear the following

> A: And then, triple 1s: Snake eyes win five times the original wager.
>   B: Five times!?
>   A: Don't worry about it. They don't come up that often. And then there's the “pisser”. If a die **rolls out of the bowl**, we treat it as a bust. Even if the dealer **rolls a pisser** he loses. And if you roll a pisser you're not allowed to reroll.

The term “pisser” probably refers to what is called **[urine backsplash](https://www.bbc.com/news/science-environment-24820279)**, this occurs when someone (usually a man) urinating either misaims the toilet or their urine stream **splashes out** of the (lavatory) **bowl**, just like a die thrown in a bowl might rebound and fall out.

In *Oxford Dictionaries*, a [pisser](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/pisser) is slang for

> 1. A person who urinates.
>
>    1.1 A toilet.
>
>    1.2 *[in singular]*
>      An annoying or disappointing event or circumstance.

Comment: Thank you for editing also. I would like yours to be the answer ( since "splashing out" ( like urine ) is very understandable ) but reversing the original choice is a bit hard for me, so please excuse me^^^^.

Comment: @KentaroTomono no problem, I liked the question and I just wanted to support Lambie's answer.